# Como puedo mandar salida en un jTextField en Java

Tags: jtextfield

Quiero saber porque al momento de imprimir mi arreglo en un jTextField, simplemente me arroja el ultimo dato de mi arreglo, ayuda.

```
double []array=new double[100];
    for(j=0;j<100;j++){
        array[j]=Math.random();
        JTFusuarios.setText(+j+"//"+array[j]);
    }
```

Es un arreglo de numeros aleatorios.
Todo esta dentro de un jFrame, es una interfaz
[image: Este es un ejemplo de como me manda a salida el codigo anteriorintroducir el código aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que obtener los datos cada vez que va interactuando el for, segun tu codigo solo imprimes el ultimo dato del arreglo, porque el settext va reemplazandos los valores y al final te queda el ultimo, la solucion es obtener el dato anterior y ir agregar el que sigue lo haces con getText();

```
double []array=new double[100];
    for(j=0;j<100;j++){
        array[j]=Math.random();
        JTFusuarios.setText(JTFusuarios.getText()+j+"//"+array[j]+"\n");
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono¡¡